# Check my proof (radius of convergence)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

I have a series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n$ with $1/n^2\leq a_n\leq 1/n$ and I need to find its radius of convergence, R.

Here's what I've done:

Since $1/n^2\leq a_n\leq 1/n$, we have $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^n/n^2\leq \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^n/n$. Additionally, since $\lim_{n\to \infty}|(n+1)^2/n^2|=1$, the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^n/n^2$ has a radius of convergence of 1 and thus R is at least 1. Similarly since $\lim_{n\to \infty}|(n+1/n|=1$, the radius of convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^n/n$ is also 1, and thus R is 1 at most. This implies that R is exactly 1.

Does this seem fine? Do I need to specify why R is between the radii of convergence of the two other series, or is this clear enough? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is fine and imo sufficient, but you could as well derive directly $\sqrt[n]{a_n}\to1$ from the hypothesis (by the squeeze theorem).

Comment: I don't think you can compare the sums, since $x$ can be either positive or negative. But it is true for example that $lim \sqrt[n]{a_n}$ exists and is equal to $1$, hence your radius of convergence is $R=1$.

Comment: 1)  comparing the sums for $x>0$ is sufficient 2) yes this was the 2nd part of my previous comment

Comment: @AnneBauval thank you! Though I'm not sure how to work out the proof with the squeeze theorem.

Answer (score 1):

As noted by @GReyes , your comparisons of sums are valid only for $x\ge0.$ For your proof to be complete, just argue that this is sufficient ($R$ is determined by the fact that the series is convergent for every $x\in[0,R)$ and divergent for every $x>R$).

But you could as well derive directly the result in the following way: $\sqrt[n]{\frac1n}=e^{-\frac{\ln n}n}\to e^0=1$ and $\sqrt[n]{\frac1{n^2}}=\left(\sqrt[n]{\frac1n}\right)^2\to1^2,$ hence ([squeezing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem)+[Cauchy-Hadamard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Hadamard_theorem)) $\frac1R=\lim\sqrt[n]{a_n}=1.$